# Selecionar Todos os Registros NULL e NOT NULL

Tags: mysql

Tenho duas tabelas:

**Medalhas** e **Loja_Medalhas**.

Quero trazer em apenas um `SELECT` todas as medalhas e criar uma coluna para colocar sua situação. Seriam dois status, **Yes** e **No**.

As estruturas:

**MEDALHAS**

```
ID
MEDALHA
```

**LOJA_MEDALHAS**

```
ID
NOME
ID_MEDALHA
```

Estou fazendo o seguinte `SELECT` abaixo:

```
SELECT 
    ID_LOJA,
    MEDALHAS.ID,
    MEDALHA,
    CASE LOJA_MEDALHA.ID_MEDALHA
    WHEN NULL THEN 'NÃO'
    ELSE 'SIM' END AS SITUACAO
FROM
    MEDALHAS
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    LOJA_MEDALHA
ON
    LOJA_MEDALHA.ID_MEDALHA = MEDALHAS.ID OR LOJA_MEDALHA.ID_MEDALHA <> MEDALHAS.ID
WHERE
    ID_LOJA = 1
```

Essa consulta está trazendo todas **Yes**. Sendo que adicionei apenas uma medalha para a loja.

Quero trazer todas para poder exibir na minha página a medalha acesa ou apagada dependendo do seu status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui.

```
SELECT 
    ID_LOJA, 
    MEDALHAS.ID, 
    ID_MEDALHA,
    MEDALHA,
    CASE WHEN LOJA_MEDALHAS.ID_MEDALHA IS NULL
    THEN 'NÃO'
    ELSE 'SIM' END AS SITUACAO
FROM 
    MEDALS 
LEFT JOIN 
    LOJA_MEDALHAS ON LOJA_MEDALHAS.ID_MEDALHA = MEDALHAS.ID
AND 
    ID_LOJA = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Ao [trabalhar com valores NULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/working-with-null.html) no MySQL, utilize `IS NULL` e `IS NOT NULL` para verificar essa condição:

```
WHEN LOJA_MEDALHAS.ID_MEDALHA IS NULL
```